# PDO Exception Error - How to resolve this?

Tags: 7

After integrating Google Custom search in Drupal 7, I am getting this error page. What should I do to resolve this error?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a MySQL configuration issue - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Or, quoting after http://drupal.org/node/930876#comment-4519490:

> If MySQL connections are not closed
>   properly, then you might have an error
>   within the code somewhere, that leads
>   the script to end prematurely.
>
> In standard cases, connections are
>   properly closed.
>
> Look at the detailed error log of your
>   server, or activate on page error
>   reporting if you're on a develpment
>   site. You might find something useful,
>   such as a forgotten dsm() somewhere
>   with the devel module not being
>   activated.
>
> The error might not be displayed and
>   leads the site to look as usual, but
>   the PHP process is not ended properly,
>   leaving MySQL connections opened.

Start with checking your error logs and try to find out why this could be happening there.

Answer (score 0):

This should also help:

### DEADLOCK

Reading/surfing I found that InnoDB tables can have this problem. One of the causes is the very high traffic and loss of connections (but deadlock is even something different). Combined you may easily reach the max_users_connection limit and this will render your site useless.

Some Hints:

- use cache, if you can
- use throttle
- use bad behaviour module (as this should shield you against spammers)
- set interactive_timeout so that your connections expire quickly

I have made these changes to the **database.mysql.inc** - to the function `mysql_connect`

the old version:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($url['host'], $url['user'], $url['pass'], TRUE) or die(mysql_error());
```

the new version:

```
 $connection = mysql_connect($url['host'], $url['user'], $url['pass'], TRUE, MYSQL_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("SET SESSION interactive_timeout=120", $connection);
```

To get the timeout run `phpinfo()` and watch for the connection timeout inside your MySQL, and also timeout of your apache process (or IIS if you use IIS).

Basically, after the timeout, your script will be cut off, BUT the opened connection will be there eating out of your `max_users_connections`. If you set the `interactive_timeout` limit, it will be closed automatically (note: mysql has a global `wait_timeout` limit, but as a default there is often 28800 = 8 hours, the connection will expire in 8 hours!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your php.ini/php configuration in your cpanel.  I moved up to php5.5 from 5.4 and this problem was gone.